# Questions about scrapy, why can't I parse the whole page, but just the first record on the page?

Tags: javascript, python, html, scrapy

I am new to scrappy, and trying to follow an example to (link http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/08/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/#.VcFiAjBVhBc) to crawl craiglist.

However, every time I run my code, I can only obtain the first record on the page, and the sample from the codes attached is like this, which only contains the first record on each page

```
link,title
/eby/npo/5155561393.html,Residential Administrator full time
/sfc/npo/5154403251.html,Sr. Director of Family Support Services
/eby/npo/5150280793.html,Veterans Program Internship
/eby/npo/5157174843.html,PROTECT OUR LIFE SAVING MEDICINE! $10-15/H
/eby/npo/5143949422.html,Program Supervisor - Multisystemic Therapy (MST)
/sby/npo/5145782515.html,Housing Specialist -- Santa Clara and Alameda Counties
/nby/npo/5148193893.html,Shipping Assistant for Non Profit
/sby/npo/5142160649.html,Companion for People with Developmental Disabilities
/sfc/npo/5139127862.html,Director of Vocational Services
```

and i used "scrapy crawl craig2 -o items_2.csv -t csv" to run the code.
Thanks in advance for the help

Codes are:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider#, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from scrapy.http import Request
class CraigslistSampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()



class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craig2"
    allowed_domains = ["sfbay.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/"]

   # rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("index\d00\.html", ),restrict_xpaths=('//p[@class="button next"]',))
   # , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    #)


    def start_requests(self):
            for i in range(9):
                yield Request("http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo?s=" + str(i) + "00" , self.parse_items)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//span[@class="pl"]')
        items = []
        for ii in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item ["title"] = ii.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = ii.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
            return(items)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "craig2"
    allowed_domains = ["sfbay.craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/npo?s=%s" % i for i in xrange(1,9)]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select('//span[@class="pl"]')
        items = []
        for ii in titles:
            item = CraigslistSampleItem()
            item ["title"] = ii.select("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = ii.select("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
            yield item
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem of your code is that you do `return(items)` in your `for` loop. This means that you are returning right after the first title. So even if you have 100 titles on each page you will return the first one. So shift the `return(items)` one block to the left and you are good:

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select('//span[@class="pl"]')
    items = []
    for ii in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item ["title"] = ii.select("a/text()").extract()
        item ["link"] = ii.select("a/@href").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return(items)
```

Note that in this case the `return(items)` is on the same indentation-level as the `for` loop and not in the loop. This returns on my machine 900 entries in the CSV output.

The [solution of Ooorza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31823914/3941341) is good too but you do not need all of it. In this case solution is to `yield` each `item` in the loop. In this case you convert your `for` loop to a generator function which sends the parsed item to further processing. In this case you do not need to `append` the current item to the list. The `parse_items` method would look like this:

```
def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select('//span[@class="pl"]')
    for ii in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        item ["title"] = ii.select("a/text()").extract()
        item ["link"] = ii.select("a/@href").extract()
        yield item
```